# Android 3.2 Strange view issues

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-3.0-honeycomb, tabbar

I'm new to Android development, and was testing my application in the 3.2 simulator to ensure that everything scales correctly on a tablet. The view consists of a ListView in a TabBar, and I am experiencing strange issues with misalignment of the UI (See link). This is not present on any other OS version (2.1 - 4.0) on any of the phone screen sizes.

The `ListView` items consist of a custom layout that uses a `LinearLayout` with a background drawable and two `textviews` for the title and subtitle.

[image]

XML Render (10.1in WXGA Tab):

[image]

Has anybody got any ideas?

EDIT:

Fixed the issue. I had disabled rotation on my TabBar views in my manifest, by removing this line of code in the XML the list renders as desired. Thanks for all those who contributed.

Comment: This is quite strange, hard to say though without (a small/self contained) version of your views / xml. could it be just a fail from the emulator?

Comment: I think it might be a fail from the emulator, as the preview on the layout xml of the list view item renders perfectly (see edited post)

Comment: I have a (partly unjustified probably) really bad feeling about the Android SDK and mac (as you seem to be using?). It can be unbearably annoying in my experience. Is there a fellow dev. you can ask to take a look at it on a diffent machine, or even install a vmware linux environment and check it yourself in this "machine" ? Would be  sad if you put in a lot of debugging work and it is just the AVD that's failing here :)

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue, seems to be an Android issue though, the problem was that I had selectively disabled rotation on my tab bar views, and when I removed this code from the manifest the list view renders as it should. Will test it on a PC and see if the same issue arises. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can choose to load different layouts,values,and other resources as per device,locale simply changing the folders name by adding specific values,in your case use something like layout-hdpi ,layout-xhdpi

Comment: I don't think its something to do with the dpi of the screen, as the bar bar elements are simply gradients and a central image which doesn't scale, and the list view layout background images are .9 png's that scale according to the screen size